# tranwrd doesn't replace correctly and truncate target string

Tags: sas

I'm replacing the target string which is '01 -DIC-17 ' with  '01 \ 12 \ 17', then convert it to sas date with the input function, but output is '01 \ 12 \ '. truncate  the '\ 17'.

The DATA SAS is:

```
data test;
input issueDate $10. lastDate $10.;
datalines;
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
;
run;
```

I have an adjust month table:

```
DATA ADJUST_MONTH;
INPUT TARGET $ REPLACEMENT $;
DATALINES;
-ENE- /01/
-FEB- /02/
-MAR- /03/
-ABR- /04/
-MAY- /05/
-JUN- /06/
-JUL- /07/
-AGO- /08/
-SEP- /09/
-OCT- /10/
-NOV- /11/
-DIC- /12/
;
RUN;
```

Run the code:

```
 proc sql;
 update test
 set issueDate = TRANWRD(issueDate,substr(issueDate,3,5),(select replacement from adjust_month where target eq substr(issueDate,3,5)));quit;
```

The output: IssueDate: '05-DIC-16' convert en IssueDate: '05/12/'

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do all the transformations in your code.  You can use the relevant language date informat to read the data directly.  In your case it is in Spanish, so the `espdfde9.` informat will read the source data as a date (using the `input` function), then you can do with it as you please.

I would create extra columns to store these dates, rather than update the exisitng columns, for the reason that dates are generally better stored as numbers instead of character.  But it's your choice.

To use this informat, your SAS installation has to have European character sets and encoding loaded.

```
data test;
input issueDate $10. lastDate $10.;
datalines;
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 04-ENE-17
05-DIC-16 20-ENE-17
;
run;


data want;
set test;
issuedate_new = input(issuedate, espdfde9.);
lastdate_new = input(lastdate, espdfde9.);
format issuedate_new lastdate_new date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `replacement` column contains trailing blanks. `Trim` or similar functions will help you. For example, replace the nested select by `trim((select replacement from adjust_month where target eq substr(issueDate,3,5)))`,

Comment: Thanks for your help @Petr

Comment: I advise against using the `trim()` function.  Instead consider `trimn()` or preferably `cats()`.  The `trim()` function itself does not behave as many people expect and can cause hard to debug problems.  The full description of the function is:  "Removes trailing blanks from a character string, and returns one blank if the string is missing.".  Usually people want to trim both front and trailing blanks, so `trim()` misses the target there, additionally, returning a single space instead of an empty string is horrible behaviour.